Plotting trees in R?
I have a hierarchical dataset in R that looks like this:
library(data.tree)

desserts <- Node$new("Desserts")

cakes <- desserts$AddChild("Cakes")
cakes_chocolate <- cakes$AddChild("Chocolate")
cakes_chocolate$AddChild("Dark Chocolate")
cakes_chocolate$AddChild("Milk Chocolate")
cakes_vanilla <- cakes$AddChild("Vanilla")
cakes_vanilla$AddChild("French Vanilla")
cakes_vanilla$AddChild("Classic Vanilla")
cakes_red_velvet <- cakes$AddChild("Red Velvet")
cakes_red_velvet$AddChild("Cream Cheese Frosting")
cakes_red_velvet$AddChild("Buttercream Frosting")
cakes_carrot <- cakes$AddChild("Carrot")
cakes_carrot$AddChild("Walnut")
cakes_carrot$AddChild("Pineapple")

cookies <- desserts$AddChild("Cookies")
cookies_chocolate_chip <- cookies$AddChild("Chocolate Chip")
cookies_chocolate_chip$AddChild("Double Chocolate Chip")
cookies_chocolate_chip$AddChild("White Chocolate Chip")
cookies_oatmeal_raisin <- cookies$AddChild("Oatmeal Raisin")
cookies_oatmeal_raisin$AddChild("Cinnamon")
cookies_oatmeal_raisin$AddChild("Nutmeg")
cookies_peanut_butter <- cookies$AddChild("Peanut Butter")
cookies_peanut_butter$AddChild("Crunchy")
cookies_peanut_butter$AddChild("Smooth")
cookies_sugar <- cookies$AddChild("Sugar")
cookies_sugar$AddChild("Frosted")
cookies_sugar$AddChild("Plain")

ice_cream <- desserts$AddChild("Ice Cream")
ice_cream_vanilla <- ice_cream$AddChild("Vanilla")
ice_cream_vanilla$AddChild("French Vanilla")
ice_cream_vanilla$AddChild("Classic Vanilla")
ice_cream_chocolate <- ice_cream$AddChild("Chocolate")
ice_cream_chocolate$AddChild("Dark Chocolate")
ice_cream_chocolate$AddChild("Milk Chocolate")
ice_cream_strawberry <- ice_cream$AddChild("Strawberry")
ice_cream_strawberry$AddChild("Fresh Strawberry")
ice_cream_strawberry$AddChild("Strawberry Swirl")
ice_cream_mint_chocolate_chip <- ice_cream$AddChild("Mint Chocolate Chip")
ice_cream_mint_chocolate_chip$AddChild("Dark Chocolate Chips")
ice_cream_mint_chocolate_chip$AddChild("Milk Chocolate Chips")

pies <- desserts$AddChild("Pies")
pies_apple <- pies$AddChild("Apple")
pies_apple$AddChild("Classic Apple")
pies_apple$AddChild("Caramel Apple")
pies_pumpkin <- pies$AddChild("Pumpkin")
pies_pumpkin$AddChild("Spiced Pumpkin")
pies_pumpkin$AddChild("Classic Pumpkin")
pies_pecan <- pies$AddChild("Pecan")
pies_pecan$AddChild("Chocolate Pecan")
pies_pecan$AddChild("Classic Pecan")
pies_cherry <- pies$AddChild("Cherry")
pies_cherry$AddChild("Sweet Cherry")
pies_cherry$AddChild("Tart Cherry")

pastries <- desserts$AddChild("Pastries")
pastries_croissant <- pastries$AddChild("Croissant")
pastries_croissant$AddChild("Butter Croissant")
pastries_croissant$AddChild("Almond Croissant")
pastries_danish <- pastries$AddChild("Danish")
pastries_danish$AddChild("Cheese Danish")
pastries_danish$AddChild("Fruit Danish")
pastries_eclair <- pastries$AddChild("Eclair")
pastries_eclair$AddChild("Chocolate Eclair")
pastries_eclair$AddChild("Vanilla Eclair")
pastries_cinnamon_roll <- pastries$AddChild("Cinnamon Roll")
pastries_cinnamon_roll$AddChild("Classic Cinnamon Roll")
pastries_cinnamon_roll$AddChild("Pecan Cinnamon Roll")

print(desserts)

I run into a problem when trying to plot this data:
plot(desserts)


Can someone please help try and plot this hierarchical data in a different way such that it is more visible and easier to read? As such, the text is too small to read and barely visible. Is it possible to orient the plot in a different way, or use a different way all together to avoid these problems?

Maybe using interactive plots is an option for you: https://github.com/nanxstats/awesome-shiny-extensions?tab=readme-ov-file#tree-and-hierarchical-data

Maybe plot(desserts, output="visNetwork")

Another interactive plot: library(networkD3); radialNetwork(desserts |> ToListExplicit(unname = TRUE)).

Edward's option is really cool!

I also really like Rui's option! Is it possible to change the size of the text?
